# nginx host server log rotation all sites

Tags: nginx, lamp, logrotate

I have setup individual log files for each of my sites in the directory

```
/var/log/nginx-hosts/
```

and I have to configure log rotation for those files.  The base I am starting with is

```
/var/log/nginx-hosts/*.log {
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
    compress
}
```

however, just like apache it appears that nginx has to be shut off pre-rotation in order to actually truncate them.  The current nginx logrotate configuration is:

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 0640 www-data adm
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
        postrotate
                [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
```

should I incorporate the individual site log rotation into the primary or work to figure out the first config in a different file.  thoughts? ideas?

thank you for your help and happy holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after digging further, here is how I fixed this issue:

```
/var/log/nginx-hosts/*.access{
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 20
        compress
        dateext
        notifempty
        create 0640 www-data adm
        sharedscripts
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
        postrotate
                [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
/var/log/nginx-hosts/*.error{
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 20
        compress
        dateext
        notifempty
        create 0640 www-data adm
        sharedscripts
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
        postrotate
                [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
```